# Set different horizontal alignment of a custom UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview, alignment

Created a custom UIView 'MyLabelView' with two elements, 1x UILabel, 1x UIView which will be set to a background color.
**MyLabelView**

View:
[image]

Code:

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class MyLabelView: UIView {
@IBOutlet var contentView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    commonInit()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    commonInit()
}

override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
    super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
    commonInit()
    contentView?.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
}

private func commonInit() {
    let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
    bundle.loadNibNamed(String(describing: type(of: self)), owner: self, options: nil)

    addSubview(contentView)
}
```

}

I'm using MyLabelView on two occasions:
- MasterViewController (TableViewController with dynamic prototypes)
- DetailViewController (TableViewController with static cells and grouped style)

**MasterViewController**
Shows MyLabelView correct as part of a custom UITableViewCell
View:
[image] 

Code (in cellForRowAt):

```
let cell: MyTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyTableViewCell") as! MyTableViewCell
cell.myLabelView.titleLabel.text = "Label"
cell.myLabelView.imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

// Dynamic width to fit label texts of various sizes
var frm: CGRect = cell.myLabelView.titleLabel.frame
frm.size.width = cell.myLabelView.titleLabel.intrinsicContentSize.width
cell.myLabelView.titleLabel.frame = frm
```

**DetailViewController**
Here I would like to render MyLabelView with increased font size (working) and right-aligned so that no matter how long the Label text is, it is always aligned next to the chevron
View:
[image] 

Code (in viewDidLoad):

```
myLabelView.titleLabel.text = "Label"
myLabelView.titleLabel.font = myLabelView.titleLabel.font.withSize(17)
myLabelView.imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

// Dynamic width to fit label texts of various sizes
var frm: CGRect = myLabelView.titleLabel.frame
frm.size.width = myLabelView.titleLabel.intrinsicContentSize.width
myLabelView.titleLabel.frame = frm
```

**Expected results**
View:
[image]

View:
[image]

I tried to play around with additional, outer UIViews as containers and using AutoLayout, but somehow it never worked as I expected it. Thank you very much for your help.
Swift 4, iOS11

***UPDATE***
I tried to set the constraints in IB as I don't have access to the cell (using static cells).
Content View:
[image]

Title:
[image]

MyLabelView:
[image]

Comment: Could you share your code or autolayout constraints for that table view cell which contains your custom label? There is likely a different way to include your custom label in the cell that will work.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a function to the UITableViewCell subclass and call it when you need to set the view next to the right side:

```
func setTrailingAnchorForView() {
        contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        contentView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        contentView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    }
```

Call it like this:

```
cell.setTrailingAnchorForView()
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. MyLabelView is accessed through an IBOutlet and defined in viewDidLoad() of DetailViewController. This DetailViewController uses static cells thus I don't use cellForRowAt which eliminates solutions where I have access to the containing cell.
Can I set your constraints in code without having access to the cell? I tried it in IB again but I'm not succeeding with the dynamic trailing.. The question is updated with the IB setting if you could take a look. Thank you very much